# I have finished my scene and there is just an issue, I can walk through my GLTF (GLB) model and the water dosent hit it

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, gltf

I am trying to finish my website where this scene is integrated. I would like the user using pointerlock controls to not be able to run into the GLTF Model, as it doesn't look very professional. How would you go about this? I was told to use DRACO and a physics collider but don't know how to implement them.

thanks in advance for your help. I can't link the js and CSS to the HTML properly so here is a link to the finished product, that I am also trying to make responsive but maybe for the the next question. : https://exhibition1-la-disconnect-3-0.netlify.app/examples/index-on-water.html

```js
 
    import * as THREE from "three";
import { PointerLockControls } from "/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js";
// import { PointerLockControls as MobilePointerLockControls } from "/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControlsMobile.js";
// import  {FBXLoader} from "/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXloader.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
    // import { KTX2Loader } from 'three/addons/loaders/KTX2Loader.js';
    import { Water } from 'three/addons/objects/Water.js';
    // import { PositionalAudioHelper } from 'three/addons/helpers/PositionalAudioHelper.js';
let camera, scene, renderer, controls, water;


const objects = [];
 
let raycaster;                     //This class is designed to assist with raycasting. Raycasting is used for mouse picking (working out what objects in the 3d space the mouse is over) amongst other things.

let moveForward = false;           //movement variables
let moveBackward = false;
let moveLeft = false;
let moveRight = false;
let canJump = false;               //movement variables

let prevTime = performance.now(); //time.now
const velocity = new THREE.Vector3();  // velocity is a phenomenon with 2 properties magnitude and direction
const direction = new THREE.Vector3();


// const startButton = document.getElementById( 'startButton' );
//      startButton.addEventListener( 'click', init );

init();      
animate();


function init() {
    // const overlay = document.getElementById( 'overlay' );
    //      overlay.remove();

    //      const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
//camera and position
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(     
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    2000
  );
  camera.position.y = 120;
  camera.position.z = -1000;
  camera.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 6;
  camera.rotation.y = Math.PI; // Rotate camera 180 degrees
   // camera.position.z = -1000;




// const reflectionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
//              .setPath( 'textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/' )
//              .load( [ 'px.jpg', 'nx.jpg', 'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg', 'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg' ] );


    // Function to increase camera size
    function increaseCameraSize() {
      const maxCameraSize = 100; // Maximum camera size
      if (camera.scale.x < maxCameraSize) {
        camera.scale.multiplyScalar(0.9); // Decrease camera size by 10%
        updateCameraSizeIndicator();
      }
    }

    // Function to decrease camera size
    function decreaseCameraSize() {
      const minCameraSize = 0.1; // Minimum camera size
      if (camera.scale.x > minCameraSize) {
        camera.scale.divideScalar(0.9); // Increase camera size by 10%
        updateCameraSizeIndicator();
      }
    }

    // Update camera size indicator on the screen
    function updateCameraSizeIndicator() {
      const cameraSizeIndicator = document.getElementById("camera-size");
      cameraSizeIndicator.textContent = camera.scale.x.toFixed(1);
    }




//background and fog
  scene = new THREE.Scene();                         
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  const skyLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
  //sky texture-clouds
const skytexture = skyLoader.load([
    './resources/yellowcloud_ft.jpg',
    './resources/yellowcloud_bk.jpg',
    './resources/yellowcloud_up.jpg',
    './resources/yellowcloud_dn.jpg',
    './resources/yellowcloud_rt.jpg',
    './resources/yellowcloud_lf.jpg',
]);
scene.background = skytexture;
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x8A5000, 0, 300);

//lighting
  const ambientLight =new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75)
  ambientLight.intensity =0.5;
  scene.add(ambientLight)

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75);
  light.position.set(130, 100, 100);
  light.intensity=1;
  //shadows
  light.castShadow = true; 
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1000;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1000;
  light.shadow.camera.near = 2;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 1500;
  light.shadow.camera.near = 2;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 1500;
  light.shadow.camera.left = 1500;
  light.shadow.camera.right = -1500;
  light.shadow.camera.top = 1000;
  light.shadow.camera.bottom = -1000;
  

  scene.add(light);
//defining pointerlock
  controls = new PointerLockControls(camera, document.body);

//html controls info
  const blocker = document.getElementById("blocker");
  const instructions = document.getElementById("instructions");

//pointerlock system
  //lock
  instructions.addEventListener("click", function () {
    controls.lock();
  });

  controls.addEventListener("lock", function () {
    instructions.style.display = "none";
    blocker.style.display = "none";
  });
  //unlock
  controls.addEventListener("unlock", function () {
    blocker.style.display = "block";
    instructions.style.display = "";
  });
//movement controls

  scene.add(controls.getObject());
//keydown
  const onKeyDown = function (event) {           
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowUp":
      case "KeyW":
        moveForward = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "KeyA":
        moveLeft = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowDown":
      case "KeyS":
        moveBackward = true;
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
      case "KeyD":
        moveRight = true;
        break;

      case "Space":
        if (canJump === true) velocity.y += 300;
        canJump = false;
        break;
    }
  };
//keyup
  const onKeyUp = function (event) {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowUp":
      case "KeyW":
        moveForward = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
      case "KeyA":
        moveLeft = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowDown":
      case "KeyS":
        moveBackward = false;
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
      case "KeyD":
        moveRight = false;
        break;
    }
  };



  document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
                        console.log("touch")
                        moveForward = true;
                    })
                    document.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
                        console.log("end")
                        moveForward = false;
                    })

                document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );
// MOBILE TOUCH CONTROLS
// Touch controls
const touchControls = document.getElementById("touch-controls");
  const upArrow = document.getElementById("up-arrow");
  const leftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow");
  const downArrow = document.getElementById("down-arrow");
  const rightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow");
    const jumpButton = document.getElementById("jump-button");

// Add touch event listeners to the touch controls
touchControls.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart, false);
touchControls.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd, false);

// Touch control variables
let touchX = null;
let touchY = null;

// Function to handle touch start event
function handleTouchStart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const touches = event.touches;
  if (touches && touches.length > 0) {
    const touch = touches[0];
    touchX = touch.clientX;
    touchY = touch.clientY;
    handleTouchMove(touch);
  }
}

// Function to handle touch end event
function handleTouchEnd(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  touchX = null;
  touchY = null;
}

// Function to handle touch move event
function handleTouchMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!touchX || !touchY) {
    return;
  }
  const touch = event.touches[0];
  const deltaX = touch.clientX - touchX;
  const deltaY = touch.clientY - touchY;
  touchX = touch.clientX;
  touchY = touch.clientY;

  // Determine movement direction based on touch movement
  if (deltaY < -10) {
    moveForward();
  } else if (deltaY > 10) {
    moveBackward();
  }
  if (deltaX < -10) {
    moveLeft();
  } else if (deltaX > 10) {
    moveRight();
  }
}

// Function to handle jump button touch start event
function handleJumpButtonTouchStart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jump();
}

// Add touch event listener to the jump button
jumpButton.addEventListener("touchstart", handleJumpButtonTouchStart, false);

//event listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);

// Event listener for double click
 // Event listener for double click
 document.addEventListener("dblclick", onDoubleClick);
    // Event listener for key press
    document.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress);
    // Function to handle double click event
    function onDoubleClick() {
      // Move the camera 10px forward
      moveCameraForward(10);
    }
    // Function to handle key press event
    function onKeyPress(event) {
      if (event.key === "m") {
        // Increase camera size
        increaseCameraSize();
      } else if (event.key === "n") {
        // Decrease camera size
        decreaseCameraSize();
      }
    }
    // Function to move the camera forward
    function moveCameraForward(distance) {
      // Get the current camera position and rotation
      const position = camera.position.clone();
      const rotation = camera.rotation.clone();
      // Calculate the forward vector
      const direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
      direction.applyQuaternion(rotation);
      // Move the camera forward by the specified distance
      position.add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance));
      // Teleport the camera horizontally on the floor
      teleport(position.x, position.y);
    }
    // Function to increase camera size
    function increaseCameraSize() {
      const maxCameraSize = 10; // Maximum camera size
      if (camera.scale.x < maxCameraSize) {
        camera.scale.multiplyScalar(1.1); // Increase camera size by 10%
      }
    }
    // Function to decrease camera size
    function decreaseCameraSize() {
      const minCameraSize = 1; // Minimum camera size
      if (camera.scale.x > minCameraSize) {
        camera.scale.divideScalar(1.1); // Decrease camera size by 10%
      }
    }
// document.addEventListener("dblclick", onDoubleClick);

// //

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(   
    new THREE.Vector3(),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0),
    0,
    10 
  );
// // floor/plane

// Water

const waterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10000, 10000);

water = new Water(
    waterGeometry,
    {
        textureWidth: 512,
        textureHeight: 1000,
        waterNormals: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/waternormals.jpg', function ( texture ) {

            texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

        } ),
        sunDirection: new THREE.Vector3(),
        sunColor: 0xffffff,
        waterColor: 0x001e0f,
        distortionScale: 3.7,
        fog: scene.fog !== undefined
    }
);

water.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;

scene.add( water );


  //GLTF house

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();

  loader.load( 'models/gltf/Photography-museum.glb', function ( glb ) {
    const model = glb.scene;
    scene.add(model);
    model.position.set(0,-15,-50);
    
    model.scale.set(1,1,1);
    model.rotateY(-0.9);
    model.traverse(function(node) {
      if(node.isMesh)
      node.castShadow = true;
      node.receiveShadow=true;
    });

  }, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
  } );



  // renderer size pixel ratio.. 

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; //shadows
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
;

  //resizing listener

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

  //end of init function
}


// function that does the resize
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  const vrButton = VRButton.createButton(renderer);

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


//animation and movement diplayed
function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  //const time = performance.now() * 0.001;



water.material.uniforms[ 'time' ].value += 1.0 / 60.0;  

//time variable so animation is updated on time not device perfomance
  const time = performance.now();


//the mouse movement once clicked and pointerlock is enabled
  if (controls.isLocked === true) {
    raycaster.ray.origin.copy(controls.getObject().position);
    raycaster.ray.origin.y -= 10;

    const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

    const onObject = intersections.length > 0;

    const delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

    velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
    velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

    velocity.y -= 7 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass

//adding movement to the event listeners mentioned in the init function
    direction.z = Number(moveForward) - Number(moveBackward);
    direction.x = Number(moveRight) - Number(moveLeft);
    direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions

    if (moveForward || moveBackward) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
    if (moveLeft || moveRight) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;
    
//allows movement sideways front and back
    controls.moveRight(-velocity.x * delta);
    controls.moveForward(-velocity.z * delta);
//jump
    controls.getObject().position.y += velocity.y * delta; // new behavior
    
//stops you from falling through the floor
    if (controls.getObject().position.y < 10) {
      velocity.y = 0;
      controls.getObject().position.y = 10;

      canJump = true;
    }
  }
//previous time from start of function
  prevTime = time;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 24px;
      overscroll-behavior: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #blocker {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    #instructions {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
/* 
      display: -webkit-box;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: box;

                -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
                box-orient: horizontal;

                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -moz-box-pack: center;
                box-pack: center;

                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -moz-box-align: center;
                box-align: center; */

      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* CONTROLS */
    span {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 1px;
      width: 38px;
      height: 35px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #444;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 2px #ccc;
    }

    section {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
      place-items: center;
      grid-gap: 1px;
      width: calc(46px * 3);
      height: calc(46px * 2);
    }

    section~section {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    section>span:nth-child(1) {
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 1;
    }

    section>span:nth-child(2) {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    section>span:nth-child(3) {
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    section>span:nth-child(4) {
      grid-column: 3;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

  

    .size-indicator-right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      color: white;
    }
    .size-indicator-left{
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      color: white;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        /* smooth scrolling on iOS devices */
   body {-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
  </style>


  <!-- Add the necessary meta tags for responsive layout -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

 <!-- Add CSS styles for touch controls -->
 <style>
  #touch-controls {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .touch-button {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
```

```html
<script>

  var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  if (isMobile) {
    document.getElementById("instructions").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "none";
  }

</script>
  <!-- Touch controls -->
<!-- Touch controls -->
<!-- <div id="touch-controls" style="display: none;">
  <div class="arrow-button" id="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="down-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="right-arrow"></div>
  <div id="jump-button"></div>
</div> -->
  <div id="touch-controls">
    <!-- Add your touch controls HTML here -->
    <!-- For example: -->
    <button id="up-button">Up</button>
    <button id="left-button">Left</button>
    <button id="down-button">Down</button>
    <button id="right-button">Right</button>
    <button id="jump-button">Jump</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    // Add your Three.js initialization code here

    // Check if the device is a mobile device
    const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    // Show touch controls only on mobile devices
    const touchControls = document.getElementById("touch-controls");
    if (isMobile) {
      touchControls.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      touchControls.style.display = "none";
    }

    // Add touch control functionality for mobile devices
    if (isMobile) {
      const moveForwardButton = document.getElementById("up-button");
      const moveLeftButton = document.getElementById("left-button");
      const moveBackwardButton = document.getElementById("down-button");
      const moveRightButton = document.getElementById("right-button");
      const jumpButton = document.getElementById("jump-button");

      moveForwardButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        moveForward = true;
      });
      moveForwardButton.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        moveForward = false;
      });

      moveLeftButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        moveLeft = true;
      });
      moveLeftButton.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        moveLeft = false;
      });

      moveBackwardButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        moveBackward = true;
      });
      moveBackwardButton.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        moveBackward = false;
      });

      moveRightButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        moveRight = true;
      });
      moveRightButton.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        moveRight = false;
      });

      jumpButton.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
        jump();
      });
    }
  </script> 

  <div id="blocker">
    <div id="instructions">
      <p id="playplayplay" style="font-size: 1.5em;border-radius: 100px;padding:20px;margin:20px;border: 1px solid white;width:30%;">Click to play
      </p>
  
        <section>
          <span>W</span>
          <span>A</span>
          <span>S</span>
          <span>D</span>
        </section>
        <section>
          <span>&uarr;</span>
          <span>&larr;</span>
          <span>&darr;</span>
          <span>&rarr;</span>
        </section><br />

        Look Around: MOUSE <br />
        Jump: SPACEBAR
     
          <span style="margin-top: 20px;">M</span>
          <p style="margin-top: 10px;"> Press multiple times to MOVE faster with less fog.</p> 
          <span style="margin-top: 20px;">N</span>   <p style="margin-top: 10px;">Press in increments to come back to NORMAL view.</p> 
     
    
      <p style="margin-top: 20px;">
        © Exhibition — La Disconnect 3.0 | Amba Amba Studio | Geneva
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>



    <!-- <audio loop id="music" preload="auto" style="display: none">
        <source src="sounds/376737_Skullbeatz___Bad_Cat_Maste.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="sounds/376737_Skullbeatz___Bad_Cat_Maste.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>



    <div id="overlay">
    
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info">
      
  <button id="startButton">Play</button>
        <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">three.js</a> webaudio - orientation<br/>
        music by <a href="http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/376737" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">skullbeatz</a>
    </div> -->

  <script type="importmap">
    {
          "imports": {
            "three": "../build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
          }
        }
      </script>

  <!-- Touch controls -->
<!-- Touch controls -->
<!-- <div id="touch-controls" style="display: none;">
  <div class="arrow-button" id="up-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="left-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="down-arrow"></div>
  <div class="arrow-button" id="right-arrow"></div>
  <div id="jump-button"></div>
</div> -->
<!-- 
<script>
  // Check if the device supports touch events
const isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

// Initialize the PointerLockControls
const controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera, document.body);

if (isTouchDevice) {
  // Enable touch controls
  controls.touchEnabled = true;

  // Disable pointer lock on touch devices
  controls.lock = () => {};
  controls.unlock = () => {};
}

// Add event listeners to handle touch events
if (isTouchDevice) {
  document.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
    controls.lock();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
    controls.unlock();
  }, false);
}

// Add the controls to the scene
scene.add(controls);

  // Check if the device is a mobile device
  const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

  // Show touch controls only on mobile devices
  const touchControls = document.getElementById("touch-controls");
  if (isMobile) {
    touchControls.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    touchControls.style.display = "none";
  }

  // Add touch control functionality for mobile devices
  if (isMobile) {
    // Handle touch events for touch controls
    document.getElementById("up-arrow").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
      moveForward = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("up-arrow").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
      moveForward = false;
    });

    document.getElementById("left-arrow").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
      moveLeft = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("left-arrow").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
      moveLeft = false;
    });

    document.getElementById("down-arrow").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
      moveBackward = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("down-arrow").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
      moveBackward = false;
    });

    document.getElementById("right-arrow").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
      moveRight = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("right-arrow").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
      moveRight = false;
    });

    document.getElementById("jump-button").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
      if (canJump === true) velocity.y += 350;
      canJump = false;
    });
  }
</script> -->
```

Comment: DRACO is only for compression. It will allow your 3D assets to download faster, but there is a cost of time spent decompressing them once they get to the browser.

Comment: Regarding the physics collider, I don't think that's necessary either, because _you_ are controlling your camera position. When computing the camera's new position, simply check if the new position would fall outside an allowed bounds. If so, prevent the movement. Given the look of your project, defining invisible walls as an alley down the gallery's main path seems reasonable.

Comment: How would you go about integrating that?

Comment: You scene looks like it's set up pretty simple, along standard axes (X,Y,Z). So imagine you're looking down the gallery, and the left and right directions are represented by values in the X axis. Imagine the left wall is at `x = -10`, and the right wall is at `x = 10`. When you create the next camera position, just check if the X value is `x >= -10 && x <= 10`. If it passes, allow the camera movement. If it doesn't pass, don't let the update happen.